# How to identify from a list of email addresses which ones are sending automatic replies, without actually emailing them?

Tags: email, outlook

hopefully this is a simple question. 
I have a list of emails and I want to identify those sending automatic replies. But Outlook does not show which addresses these are if there are more than 3. Any idea how to get them all to display?
Thanks! Mike
[Screenshot of Outlook message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlS0F.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use GetMailTips EWS operation - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877060(v=exchg.150).aspx